# Проблема с отрицательные степенями

Tags: алгоритм

В общем, есть десятичное дробное число `245,71` перевожу его в двоичное, у меня получается `11110101,010`. Проверяю свой результат: `0x2^-3 + 0x2^-2 + 0x2^-1 + 1x2^0 + 0x2^1 + 1x2^2 + 0x2^3 + 1x2^4 + 1x2^5 + 1x2^6 + 1x2^7` (вроде так все написал.) Целое число у меня получается верное: `245`, а вот если с дробным, то выходит `246,625`.

Может, я не так считаю это: "`0x2^-3 + 0x2^-2 + 0x2^-1`" ? С математикой у меня туго.((

P.S. знак умножения * заменил на x, т.к звездочку воспринимает как bb-тег.

Comment: Тут блин как не крути 71 степень не получить! число выйдет в любом случае четным, или я дурак?

Answer (score 3):

Что значит не получить 0,71? Вам, IAZ дал ссылку, где понятно расписано, что и куда. Перевод в двоичную систему дробей отличается от аналогичного перевода целых чисел.

На вашем примере 245,71:

1. Переводим 245 - это мы умеем.
2. Теперь по алгоритму (в скобках - разряд двоичного числа):

   0.71x2 = 1,42 (1) [0.5]

   0.42x2 = 0.84 (0) [0.25]

   0.84x2 = 1.68 (1) [0.125]

   0.68x2 = 1.36 (1) [0.0625]

   0.36x2 = 0.72 (0) [0.03125]

   0.72x2 = 1.44 (1) [0.015625]

   0.44x2 = 0.88 (0) [0.0078125]

   0.88x2 = 1.76 (1) [0.00390625]

   0.76x2 = 1.52 (1) [0.001953125]

   0.52x2 = 1.04 (1) [0.0009765625]

Считаем: `1x0.5 + 0x0.25 + 1x0.125 + 1x0.0625 + 0x0.03125 + 1x0.015625 + 0x0.0078125 + 1x0.00390625 + 1x0.001953125 + 1x0.0009765625 = 0,7099609375` (дальнейшие вычисления зависят от необходимой точности). Вот ваше число в двоичной системе `11110101.1011010111`.

Скажите, а что действительно в этом выражении `"0x2^-3 + 0x2^-2 + 0x2^-1"` получается 0,625? Как по мне так там, эта, типа ноль. Вы видимо единицу во втором разряде потеряли. Но даже в таком случае 0,625 как-то не выходит. В общем, что-то вы намудрили или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите как нужно [переводить дробные числа в двоичные](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BB_.D0.B2_.D0.B4.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5).

Например ваше число: 245,71 = 11110101,101101

Comment: Это немного не то... точнее то, но не для этого случая!

Comment: @Nu3oN для какого "не этого случая"? Вы о чем?